# Output inserted.Id does not throw error on fail?

Tags: sql-server-2012, output

I have several tables which have a GUID as a unique identifier. Therefor i'm using the 'OUTPUT inserted.

Id' method to return the inserted id.

This works pretty well unless the insert fails for whatever reason (in this case a FK constraint). I do not get any feedback about the failed query, it just continues as if nothing happened.

I don't have any try-catch block in my query or in my code, so the query should (at least in my opinion) throw an error.

I've tried to raise an error myself in the same query, but nothing happened.
I've also tried to remove the 'OUTPUT inserted.Id' and then the query throws an error. Building a try-catch block with and without a transaction around it didn't help either.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and am developing in c# .NET 4.0 (VS2012).

**Example query**

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name, City, Country) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES ('John', 'London', 'UK');
```

**Table Layout**

```
Id uniqueidentifier (Primary Key) Default (newid()), 
Name varchar(50), 
City varchar(50), 
Country varchar(2)
```

According to the samples i found online it should raise an error, what am i doing wrong here? Did i miss a setting in SQL Server perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i used the wrong method in my code. I was using

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("...");
com.ExecuteReader()
```

while i should be using

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("...");
com.ExecuteScalar()
```

According to the Microsoft Support Employee (and the documentation he referred to) this is the correct behaviour of these method even though it's not expected.